# Python: passing class instance to external function

Tags: python, function, instance, external

I have problem with passing class instance to  external function.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

import time    

class browser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        DEBUG("xxx")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
        DEBUG("xx: Opening browser success")
        DEBUG("xxx: Opening web page xxx")
        self.driver.get("xxxxxxxxxx") 

    def find_element(self,element): ###### Search element in Selenium by all types
        try:
            var = self.driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(element)
            DEBUG("Find Element: Element by text link " + element + " found")
            return var
        except AttributeError:
            print ("errr")
        except:
            raise Error("Error in Find Element","no-element-" + element ,self)
        else:
            print("xxx")
    def sclik(self,element):
        self.find_element(element).click()
        DEBUG("Click on "+ element )   

# Class Error: take screen,log error
class Error(Exception):
    def __init__(self,func,errorname,object1):
        pass

def DEBUG(message):
    pass
def Login(x,y):
    x.sclik(y)

gra = browser()
Login(gra,"f")
```

How can I pass "self" of instance gra to func function ?

> TypeError: sclik() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: When I run your example, I get a different error (`find_element() takes exactly 1 argument`, because you didn't define a `self` argument for `find_element).  Also, your code tries to call a `.click()` method on the return value of `find_element`, but it returns None.  And you don't show any code defining `click` or `DEBUG`.  It's unclear what you're really trying to do.  Please post a self-contained example demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Your code is correct, the problem is definitely not caused by the way you are initializing and calling the sclik function.